# How can I create multiple instances of the same model when I submit a form?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views

I have the following models:

```
class EventType(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=128)

class Event(models.Model):
    event = models.ForeignKey(EventType, null=True, blank=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    is_multiple = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    father_event = models.ForeignKey('self', null=True, blank=True)
    event_multiple = models.ManyToManyField(EventType, null=True, blank=True)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if self.name == None or self.name == '':
            self.name = self.event.name + ' - blabla'
        super(Event, self).save(*args,**kwargs)
```

I need two relations from EventType to Event, because if `is_multiple = True`, I want to add multiple event types.

Basically, if an Event is multiple, it contains many events. So, I need to create a new event for every `EventType` selected in the form. For example:

```
MultiEvent 1, is_multiple = True:
    In the form, selects 3 EventType = TypeA, TypeB, TypeC
    When I save, it creates 3 Events = TypeA - blabla, TypeB - blabla, TypeC - blabla

Each of those events has father_event = MultiEvent 1
```

I need help achieving this. Maybe you know a better way to make this.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Can't you do away with `is_multiple` and `event_multiple` and just have a `ManyToMany` field called `types`?

Comment: No, because I use `is_multiple` for other stuff (templates, views, filters, etc). Maybe with `event` and `event_multiple`, but when `is_multiple` is false, it should only have one reference with `EventType` @user3697163

Comment: What about setting is_multiple as a property on the model that returns True if the number of types is >1?

Answer (score 0):

I would do it something like that

```
class EventType(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=128)


class Event(models.Model):
    kind = models.ForeignKey(EventType, null=True, blank=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    parent = models.ForeignKey('self', related_name='children', null=True, blank=True)

###

type_list = []
for name in ('TypeA', 'TypeB', 'TypeC'):
    type_list.append(EventType.objects.create(name=name))


obj = Event.objects.create(
    kind=None, 
    name='Sample MultiEvent', 
    parent=None
)

for i, kind in enumerate(type_list):
    tmp = Event.objects.create(
        kind=kind, 
        name='Subevent {0}.{1}'.format(obj.pk, i),
        parent=obj
    )

is_event_multiple = obj.children is not None
```